# Using a web socket to detect a page exit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, socket.io

This may be a stupid question, but I have read that using the "onbeforeunload" event (to detect when a page is closed or navigated away from) is unreliable. I'm trying to record this event for a pageview tracking application. Something else I thought of was to open a web socket connection and then record when this connection closes. Is this something that would work or is it overkill and would add too much unnecessary overhead to the page? The app is using a javascript tracking code inserted into the page to be tracked and is logging to a Rails backend.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed would create too much overhead, but it may be useful to try to do this with jQuery. See if the following works for you:

```
$("html").mouseleave(function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Although this may only work when the page is navigated away from, but not closed (although I'm not 100% sure on this), it's a start.